# What is a Client Connection with User: None , Host: None , Name: compress_gtid_table in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Opening up Client Connections in MySQL Workbench I noticed a suspicious looking client connection with the following details:

```
Name:    thread/sql/compress_gtid_table  
Type:    FOREGROUND  
User:    None  
Host:    None  
DB:      None  
Schema:  None  
Command: Daemon  
Time:    [MILLIONS of seconds and constantly increasing]  
State:   Suspending  
Instrumented: YES  
Parent-Thread:  1  
Info:  Null  
Program:  None
```

I am not sure if I've provided enough information for an answer, but would someone happen to know what exactly is the purpose of this client connection (compress_gtid_table), could it be malicious, and why it would have such a large and continuously growing time value?

Experience level:
I'm fairly new to MySQL and operate solely for basic learning purposes on a local machine. I'm not familiar with threads, gtid, or daemon.

Comment: Wow, this actually affected regular database operations for me. Things got flaky... not all data would be retrieved, there were issues with locks not unlocking, and things like that. When this thread disappeared, things went back to normal. Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 8):

I know is late but I hope I can help you.

You don't have to worry.

This thread (`compress_gtid_table`) is created whenever `GTIDs` are enabled on the server. And is only running when is necessary to compress the `GTID` table because it has too many rows.

`GTIDs` are the id that will identify each transaction committed. This ids are stored in a table, that's why the number of rows can be so big and needs to be compressed.

I leave here a link for in a case you want to know more about `GTIDs`: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-gtids-concepts.html

Comment: Really appreciate the link you left to read more about `GTIDs` - very thoughtful!